# what makes a udp socker server or client

Tags: network-programming, udp, client-server

A udp sever can receive and send udp messages.
A udp client can receive and send messages.
So what makes a client and what makes a server
Is the server the side who initiates the first message or the side which does the binding on the socket or both ?

Comment: I have read many posts on stack overflow and also on the internet,  I found many contradicting explanations.

Comment: Primarily opinion based. But generally, the "server" is the endpoint waiting for a connection, while the "client" is the endpoint that initiates the connection. Note that a process can act as both server and client under these definitions, e.g. FTP in active mode. There is no uniform definition; you just need to make sure that if you are talking "server" and "client" with someone that you agree to use terminology that means the same to both of you.

Comment: Nothing really: the protocol doesn't have clients or servers; just peers. The closest you can get is that the 'server' is the one that is bound to a fixed port, if there is only one of them, but that breaks down completely in UDP multicast, where clients, or rather group members, must bind to a fixed port number.

Answer (score 1):

The server always serves client requests. By definition. This means (from this follows) that the client always sends the first message (request). To be able to receive messages, the server binds a socket. Socket binding is an instruction for the operating system to reserve a specific (local) port for your process (it does not matter if the server or client).

**UPDATE #1**

So SERVER must perform `bind()` but CLIENT can perform `bind()`. If you need to identify if the code is a SERVER you should check if this code perform `bind()` and `recv()` or `recvfrom()` BEFORE performing `send()` or `sendto()`.

Comment: Do I understand from your reply that the side which has the bind function is always the server ?